# Knockout Caching on Partial Views - Force refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, knockout.js, partial-views

I'm having an Issue with an application I'm developing using the Knockout and Knockout.mapping plugin with MVC Partial views.

**Background**

I want to implement a portal where users can have different profiles, so I give them the option to select how many profiles they want and to name them. After this they go to the next page where they configure their profiles, each profile is made up of the same Attributes and fields, at the end of the day they all go to the same table, only with a different "ProfileID"

**Current Scenario**

I have a View with only one Drop-Down list, which lists the name of the different profiles, once a profile is selected, a partialView is rendered to display the editable information to the users, here I use knockout to let users add/Delete attributes on the client side and then with an Ajax Request I post those changes into the DataBase. On the Post method on the controller I return a JSON object to update the Knockout ViewModel bound and I can do this succesfully. so far so good, right?

**Issue**

Once the users have Saved one of their profiles they will probably go to edit the next one, do whatever, and probably come back to the profiles they have already Edited. This is where the problem arises: The information displayed on the page is the one that they originally had, it means, the old one. I have traced everything and although the Data is OK in the DataBase, the thing is that the Browser doesn't even ask for the Info again to the Server, it means that is probably cached?, if so how can I force the browser to always request the info from the server, or update the cached viewModel?

**Note and Answer**
I finally realized it doesn't have to do with Knockout but just the general caching, the way to solve it was to disable the caching in the controller that would return the partial view, by adding this piece of code:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized it doesn't have to do with Knockout but just the general caching, the way to solve it was to disable the caching in the controller that would return the partial view, by adding this piece of code:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```